# Python error when installing package using wheel files

Tags: python, python-wheel, pyhook

I am trying to install pyHook with a wheel file (.whl) but for some reason it keeps giving me this error:

```
pyHook-1.5.1-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I got the wheel file from this website:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

The command I use is:

```
pip install pyHook-1.5.1-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
```

I have no idea what to do, I cant find any suggestions.

- Python version 2.7
- pip version 6.0.6

Comment: @MartijnPieters it prints win-amd64

Comment: Also, what does `pip -V` (on the command line) produce?

Comment: Oke it works now, I renamed the file to `pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl` and that did the job. Thanks for the suggestion @MartijnPieters

Comment: That is **not the right thing to do**. You are installing into Python 2.7, so get yourself the version for Python 2.7.

Comment: `pip -V` produces `pip 6.0.6 from C:\Python27\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)`

Comment: Yes, I missed that you are using Python 2.7 rather than 3.4. The output of `pip -V` just confirms it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are installing a Wheel created for Python 3.4, into Python 2.7. That won't work. Use the correct version and download the one with `cp27` in the name:

```
pyHook‑1.5.1‑cp27‑none‑win_amd64.whl
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issues whilst trying to install pyhook on Python 3.4. I downloaded the correct version from [python software foundation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyHook-3k-compiled/1.5.1).

I had to manually change the name of the file from `pyHook_3k_compiled-1.5.1-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl` to `pyHook-1.5.1-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl`.

```
pip install pyHook-1.5.1-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
```

And it worked!

Comment: your answer is much similar to @Martijn Pieters♦

Answer (score -1):

You may not have installed the correct one for your operating system check whether it is the 32 bit or 64 bit variant and install it again